# Wicket CheckBoxMultipleChoicePage & AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I'm having a weird problem in Wicket with the following code:

```
    CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String> checkBoxMultipleChoice = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<String>("multipleChoice", checkBoxModel, stringList);
    checkBoxMultipleChoice.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                //Do Something
        }            
    });
```

The onUpdate method get's called if you check/uncheck one of the checkboxes. But if you uncheck the last checked checkbox nothing happens. The onUpdate method doesnt get called.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've searched online but couldnt find anyone with the same problem.

Edit:
I use Seam Wicket 3.0.0 with wicket 1.4.15 i believe.

Comment: Works for me. Can you provide more code? What's your HTML? Also, what's your wicket version?

Comment: Does it work when you uncheck the last checkbox? So after that no checkboxes are checked. It works for me on all other cases but not that one specifically.

Comment: It seems to me this problem exists only in the case the CheckBoxMultipleChoice has set required to true. At least for me I can reproduce this error then. See user3174400s answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the identical problem and found that marking the CheckBoxMultipleChoice as not required resolved the issue.

Comment: This "workaround" is working for me, but I need one of these checkboxes to be checked. Is there any other possibility here to fix that issue?